# SQL 2005 Replication Primary Keys and Store Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, primary-key, replication

I have setup on SQL 2005 replication from a remote server which is live to a dev server which is internal. We are using pull and it sort of works. My ideal result would be that the tables structure and data is replicated along with the stored procedures, which should be possible.

However even after setting all the correct properties to replicate the primary key's etc. It still does not work, it copies all the tables and data but fails to add the primary keys to the tables, which then causes a number of store procedures to fail to replicate.

Have I missed something or is this a bug in 2005?

Luke

Comment: What is the value of `@schema_option` you pass to `sp_addarticle` when setting up the publication?

Comment: How do I check that, I have currently only be using wizards and dialog boxes no sql query.

Comment: The easiest way is to right-click the publication in the SSMS tree view and select "generate scripts"; although the bitmask is constructed from the options supplied in the wizard, not all of them are surfaced

Comment: The value is 0x000000007DFF7FF5, I actually have now managed to get the tables working with all the keys and data. When I try and replicate stored procedures is when it breaks everything. The job fails because when stored procedures are copied it can't find the primary keys on the tables referenced and the stored procedures permissions are lost.

Comment: Could you update the question with the error message and a simple example of a procedure code which is failing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a bug when setting some article properties via the wizards in SQL Server 2005.  Try using replication stored procedures to configure your publication.  This will guarantee the article properties get set properly.